# Making unmanaged dll visible to .net runtime

Tags: c#, .net

I have asp.net mvc web site.
It is using dll, written on managed C++. This library depends on other unmanaged dll.

I place unmanaged dll to some folder and add this folder to PATH variable in Environment Variables. But i guess, it is wrong way :)

What is the right way?

Comment: _" But i guess, it is wrong way"_ - why, is it not working? Then show the exception.

Comment: I make this dll global. It isn't bad?

Comment: Have you considered the unmanaged dlls could be COM components that would need to be registered with something like regsvr32.exe ?

Comment: It is external dll, I can't do something with it :)

Answer (score 0):

the order in which windows looks for dlls is as follows;

1. The same folder as the calling assembly
2. System 32
3. Locations specified in the SYSTEM Path variable

Please note the SYSTEM part for the Path. If you are running on a version of windows newer than XP, then setting the Path variable in a console window will NOT set the system Path. The system Path must be set via the Environment Variables dialog. To see this, click Start, right click on My Computer, click Properties (if W7, now click Advanced Settings). You should now have the System Properties dialog open. Go to the Advanced tab, click the Environment Variables button down on the right side. In the System Variables, scroll down until you find Path and click the Edit button. Once done, click Ok.